# printf macro for compiler with and without support for VARIADIC

Tags: c, variadic-functions

Please help me writing a `printf` macro for one compiler that supports VARIADIC and another that does not.

For instance:

```
#ifdef HAVE__VA_ARGS  
printf macro 

#else  
printf macro
```

Comment: What have you tried? We do not code for you, we will help when you run into a specific problem.

Comment: I am concentrating on the complier which doesnt support VARIADIC ,so like in that case how i will manage the arguments inside the print.

Comment: If what you mean is the support of `stdarg.h`, it is part of standard C since C89.

Comment: @Yu Hao I wanted to use the same concept for my code base , I am defining the macro for elog ,that should be suported  the both way.

Comment: All conforming C compilers support variadic functions. I think you're saying one of the compilers doesn't support variadic macros.

Comment: right keith Thompson ..i wanted the same thing u have written

Answer (score 0):

An solution with *VARIADIC* can be lock like this.

```
#define my_printf(_format, ...) { \
        printf(_format, __VA_ARGS__); \
    }
```

And if you really have an compiler without *VARIADIC*, then you have to implement an function with an variable argument list.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <std.h>
int my_printf(const char *format, ...)
{
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, dst);
  return vprintf(format, ap);
}
```